# Print output not shown when run Python script CRON

Tags: python, cron, printing

I am automatically running a simple python program from start up using `cron`. The pi boots / automatically logs in, displays the command line and runs the python program but the print output (updating count) is not displayed.

The print output works fine if I run the program via idle (ie having enabled LXDE) and it also works fine if (without running the LXDE desktop) I manually run the program from the command line, e.g. `sudo python pimon.py`

What is needed to see the print output when I start the program using `cron`?
I do not want to have to enable the LXDE desktop first.

The crontab entry is: `@reboot python /home/pi/Python27/pimon.py`

Comment: Please show your crontab entry.

Comment: Your script run by `cron` simply has no console to print its output too. The behaviour you describe is perfectly normal. Best way to work around: make your script output to a file.

Comment: Where have you told the output to go?  A cron job is not started from a terminal so is not attached to a keyboard or screen.  Perhaps you need to redirect the output to a file.

Comment: See also: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40493/log-output-of-system-script/40494#40494

Answer (score 4):

As others have noted in the comments, you need to redirect the output from the command somewhere.

This will write to a file, overwriting the file if it already exists.

```
@reboot python /home/pi/Python27/pimon.py > /path/to/output_file.txt
```

Change > to >> if you want to append to an existing file.

Check  [this link](http://sc.tamu.edu/help/general/unix/redirection.html) for more information on standard input and output redirection.

Comment: Please note that the ampersand is not necessary since `cron` already forks the program.