# How to turn on 3G connection after reboot automatically?

Tags: internet, ppp

I have functional 3G connection on my Pi but I have to turn it on manually after each reboot in Sakis3g.

Does anybody know how can that be done automatically?

Comment: which modem do you use?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to start a background process, or something that just needs to run quickly and set something up (such as networking), at boot time, is still to add it to `/etc/rc.local`.  I say "still" because it is was originally an aspect of the older [init system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) on Raspbian (SysV) which has now been replaced by **systemd**.  However, it is still supported for backward compatibility and almost certainly will be for perpetuity.

Note that it is not always as easy as it may seem; there is a [collection of questions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/search?q=rc.local+is%3Aquestion) here already about it -- you may want to refine that search if you run into problems.

Beware that if this is something that *doesn't* go quickly to the background (say 5-10 seconds), you need to fork it (`&`) so that it does, or you will screw things up.

Finally, [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40493/log-output-of-system-script) is a fairly comprehensive means of debugging problems.

Comment: Adding a `cron` @reboot is another option

Comment: Thanks, I'll get it through as I get in touch with my computer.

Comment: @Milliways: what is "cron @reboot"?

Comment: I used to love LMGTFY but have mostly given it up as a little too acerbic :/ Anyway, [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) is installed and active on Raspbian by default, has existed *for at least **4** decades*, and therefore probably has more online tutorials and other documentation  than anyone will ever want to read.  Neither Milliways nor anyone else needs to regurgitate it again.  Also note that our larger sibling site [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) is usually a better source of general linux know-how.