# Using /etc/rc.local to execute an .exe

Tags: linux

I am looking for a simple way to start a simple .exe program on every bootup using rc.local (unless there's an easier way).

Currently, the executable program I want to run is located in: /home/pi/boot and is running properly using the sudo mono command.

I am trying to make this run at boot in the rc.local and I currently just have:

```
sudo /home/pi/boot/EXENAME.exe
```

of course I have the `#!/bin/sh -e` at the top of the file but not sure exactly how I should get this working.

Comment: **Do not use `sudo` in rc.local or anything it starts unless you've intentionally changed UID.**  It's already running root.  Throwing in `sudo` cannot do anything good.   See also: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40493/log-output-of-background-or-boot-script

Comment: Are you able to successfully run your exe from an interactive command shell? If so, what command line do you type to make it run? (IE. mono /home/pi/boot/EXENAME.exe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.exe files will only run under mono. Prefix your file location with 'mono' in your script and it should work.

Comment: Thanks very much for you response. I now used: #!/bin/sh -e mono /home/pi/boot/EXENAME.exe exit 0 Which did not work. I also tried sudo mono which didn't work I must be doing something wrong. I also made rc.local executable by doing a "$ ls -l /etc/rc.local" but again nothing worked yet.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using `rc.local` assuming you are running a recent Raspbian which uses `systemd`. `systemd` will attempt to convert a well structured `sysV` script to a service, so it should still work.

An alternative for this case is to use `cron`.

You add commands to `crontab` by editing with `crontab -e`. E.g. I have `@reboot sudo python /home/pi/shutdown_daemon.py` in mine to run a program at boot.

There is a good tutorial at https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/linux/usage/cron.md

NOTE The first thing you should do (with ANY method) is run the program manually to ensure it actually works and the correct syntax.