# How to install upstart on raspberry pi 3

Tags: upstart

Getting some unmet dependencies issue trying to install upstart. Should I install upstart some other way ?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo apt-get install upstart
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
upstart is already the newest version.
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 consolekit : Depends: libck-connector0 (= 0.4.6-5) but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: libpam-ck-connector but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: `upstart` is obsolete and not used in current Raspbian. It is there only for those who disable `systemd` and will never be updated.

Comment: Sorry, I thought upstart is new way to go. What the preferred way to start my application server on os boot ?

Comment: You should create a `systemd` service, although `systemd` will attempt to convert well formed `init.d` scripts. You should ask a  new question describing what you are trying to run if you need help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Milliways points out, don't: `upstart` is [largely being abandoned in favor of `systemd`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart#Adoption).  It actually never was the default on Debian, from which Raspbian is derived.

For a version of my preferred method for using systemd [see here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45417/5538) -- although I will not promise it is the most orthodox, [the homepage](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) contains some (more) documentations links (scroll down) which should provide hours of entertainment.

I think there's a misconception amongst long-time SysV init users (a system with which systemd on Debian remains backward compatible) that SysV scripts are easier to use.  I empathize since I used to be one of them but I think this really has to do with familiarity; if you look at my methodology, running a normal shell script from a service file is no more complex than structuring a shell script for use by SysV init.  If you are trying to start something that's intended to run as a daemon service anyway it gets easier, all you need is the service file.