# How to autostart ScratchGPIO projects?

Tags: gpio, boot, raspbian-jessie, scratch

I'm working with my 7 years old son on a edukit robotics project with my son on my Raspberry PI 2, installed with Jessie.
Instead of using Python (Too complicated for him) I programmed the robot with him in scratch (default version in Jessie with scratch GPIO embedded).

However, now we want to startup the PI, so that it finally automatically executes our Scratch program (instead of connecting and launching vnc or xrdp and starting our scratch program).

I did found on the web : http://simplesi.net/autostart-scratchgpio-projects

But this seems not to work, as it seems to be obsolete (no more need to install ScratchGPIO) as this was probably written prior to Rasbian Jessie, as now it seems to startup a nuscratch image.

But I can't get around it to adapt these instructions to get this work with the current Jessie version.

Any suggestions, anyone who has solved the same issue ?

Comment: NuScratch is very much a raspberrypi.org project so you may get a quicker response if you ask this question on the raspberrypi.org forum.

Answer (score 2):

I've never used scratch myself, but there are 2 general ways to automatically start *things* on boot or login. [Here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/45358/start-python-script-at-startup-using-systemd-in-rpi-jessie) is a question similar to yours that indicates the proper way to autostart (using `systemd`), if not, look into using `cron`. They key for either case is to be able to start your *thing* directly from the command line, no clicking on stuff.

Comment: Thanks,However, the examples are pointing to a python script. This is a scratch project. I don't see how easily I can point a scheduled job cron or using systemd to set up the automatic start of a scratch project.
The idea is to upload each-time an improved version of the project to a directory, and upon reboot the PI automatically runs the scratch project (no graphics or interface required as this is a robot project).