# Flickr Photoframe

Tags: pi-3

First Pi project. Sorry in advance.

I'm trying to setup a Flickr photoframe. i followed [this instructable.](http://www.instructables.com/id/Internet-Photo-Frame/?ALLSTEPS)
When I boot the Raspberry Pi the slideshow is starting on its own. However, when I upload a new picture while this slideshow is running it closes, but it doesn't restart/reopen the slideshow script. How can i fix this?

This is the python script i'm using: (blanked out the keys)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import flickrapi
import requests
import os
import re
import time

FLICKR_KEY = "xxx"
FLICKR_SECRET = "xxx"
USER_ID = "xxx"
SET_ID = "xxx"

def make_url(photo):
# url_template = "http://farm{farm-id}.staticflickr.com/
#                 {server-id}/{id}_{secret}_[mstzb].jpg"
photo['filename'] = "%(id)s_%(secret)s_z.jpg" % photo
url = ("http://farm%(farm)s.staticflickr.com/%(server)s/%(filename)s"
       % photo)
return url, photo['filename']

def main():
#get new imaged from flickr
print " ---> Requesting photos..."
count = 0
update = False
flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(FLICKR_KEY, FLICKR_SECRET)
photos = flickr.walk_set(SET_ID)

for photo in photos:
    count += 1
    url, filename = make_url(photo.attrib)
    path = '/home/pi/photoframe/flickr/%s' % filename
    try:
        image_file = open(path)
        print " ---> Already have %s" % url
    except IOError:
        print " ---> Downloading %s" % url
        r = requests.get(url)
        image_file = open(path, 'w')
        image_file.write(r.content)
        image_file.close()
        update = True

#check to see if it needs to remove photos from folder
filelist = os.listdir("/home/pi/photoframe/flickr")
if count < len(filelist):
    print " ---> Removing photos"
    for f in filelist:
        pics = flickr.walk_set(SET_ID)
        print f
        for pic in pics:
            url, filename = make_url(pic.attrib)
            matchObj = re.match(f, filename)
            if matchObj:
                print " ---> Found %s, matched %s" %(f,filename)
                break
        else:
            print " ---> Deleting %s" %f
            os.remove("/home/pi/photoframe/flickr/%s" %f)
            update = True

#if it added or removed a photo, update slideshow
if update == True:
    print " ---> killing"
    os.system("killall feh")
    print " ---> sleep"
    time.sleep( 5 )
    print " ---> starting"
    os.system("/home/pi/bin/script_slideshow.sh")

if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: I believe that it may be because when you enter the command `os.system("kill all feh")` Python won't be able to launch your `scripy_slidedhow.sh` script because your Python process would have already been closed by then

Comment: Does your program ever even print `"--->sleep"`? I'm guessing that it doesn't because the program has probably been killed by then. But if you expect more/better advice your going to need to post the terminal output that you get when you run your script, and what you did to create said output.

Comment: May be of use: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40493/log-output-of-background-or-boot-script