# Execute a python script at srart up of raspberry pi

Tags: python, pi-3

I am trying to run a python script at the startup of pi. Python file name is `test.py`. I am using `raspberrypi-3` .

The command I have used :-

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ sudo crontab -e
```

I have added the line within it :-

```
@reboot python /home/pi/Desktop/test.py &
```

`/home/pi/Desktop` is the path of the python file.

I am rebooting the system using `sudo reboot` but script is not working automatically, where it is working manually.

Comment: Have you checked all the related posts?  People will get annoyed if this has already been answered.  If you have checked related posts you will need to edit your post and include the script and explain what part doesn't work.

Comment: See also: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/40493/5538

Answer (score 0):

`cron` is best used to run things on a timed schedule, it sometimes doesn't behave as expected at boot time. To run things at boot time under Raspbian Jessie, your best bet is to use `systemd` by following [this](http://www.raspberrypi-spy.co.uk/2015/10/how-to-autorun-a-python-script-on-boot-using-systemd/) tutorial.