# Automaticly startup BASH script stop with work after 20min

Tags: pwm, update, bash

I made Bash script what running fan for cooling. PIN20 is PWM out and this script work perfect. I run this script over therminal arroun 15 hours.

Afer all tests i register script for autoload after reboot like this:

```
$ sudo cp rpipwm.sh /etc/init.d/rpipwm.sh
$ sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/rpipwm.sh
$ sudo update-rc.d /etc/init.d/rpipwm.sh defaults
```

After last line I get this error: ***update-rc.d: error: initscript does not exist: /etc/init.d//etc/init.d/rpipwm.sh***

After that error I update with this:

```
$ sudo update-rc.d rpipwm.sh defaults
```

And reboot.

After reboot my script start to work and all is fine arround 20min. After that time my script stop to work. If I run this manualy on terminal script can work hours and hours with no errors.

What's mistake?

Here is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          rpipwm
# Required-Start:    $local_fs 
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: rpipwm
### END INIT INFO

FLAG="/var/log/rpipwm.log"
if [ ! -f $FLAG ] ;
then

        a="echo 20 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport;"
        a=$a"echo 20 > /sys/class/gpio/export;"
        a=$a"echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/direction" || true
        eval $a
        #start loop script
        i="0"
        temp="0"
        
        while true;
        do
            i=$(($i+1))
            #Read temp
            if [[ $(bc <<< "$i > 10") == 1 ]] ;
            then
                cpuTemp0=$(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)
                cpuTemp1=$(($cpuTemp0/1000))
            ##  cpuTemp2=$(($cpuTemp0/100))
                temp=$cpuTemp1
                i="0"
            fi
            a=""
            #If temperature is equal or lower than 39.99, the fan will stop spinning
            if [[ $(bc <<< "$temp < 39") == 1 ]] ;
            then
                a=$a"echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/value"
            fi
            #If temperature is between 40 and 42.99, the fan will start with 1 second burst and 1 second sleep
            if [[ $(bc <<< "$temp >= 40 && $temp <= 44") == 1 ]] ;
            then
                a=$a"echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/value; sleep 0.5; echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/value; sleep 0.1 "
            fi
            #If temperature is between 43 and 47.99, the fan will start with 1 second burst and 0.5 second sleep
            if [[ $(bc <<< "$temp >= 45 && $temp <= 49") == 1 ]] ;
            then
                a=$a"echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/value; sleep 1; echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/value; sleep 0.5" 
            fi
            #If temperature is equal or higher than 48, the fan will start spinning constantly
            if [[ $(bc <<< "$temp > 50") == 1 ]] ;
            then
                a=$a"echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/value" 
            fi
            
            eval $a
            sleep 0.1
        done
   
    touch $FLAG
fi
```

---

## **UPDATE**

---

I reorder script, put log in script and now have all to work properly and with no unexpected stop or break.

```
#!/bin/bash
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          rpipwm
# Required-Start:    $local_fs 
# Required-Stop:     $local_fs
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: rpipwm
### END INIT INFO
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/wc3/palert
FLAG="/var/log/rpipwm.log"
(
    if [ ! -f $FLAG ] ;
    then

            a="echo 20 > /sys/class/gpio/unexport;"
            a=$a"echo 20 > /sys/class/gpio/export;"
            a=$a"echo out > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/direction" || true
            eval $a
            #start loop script
            i="0"
            temp="100"
            
            while true;
            do
                i=$(($i+1))
                #Read temp
                if [[ $(bc <<< "$i > 5") == 1 ]] ;
                then
                    cpuTemp0=$(cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp)
                    cpuTemp1=$(($cpuTemp0/1000))
                ##  cpuTemp2=$(($cpuTemp0/100))
                    temp=$cpuTemp1
                    i="0"
                fi
                a=""
                #If temperature is equal or lower than 39.99, the fan will stop spinning
                if [[ $(bc <<< "$temp <= 39") == 1 ]] ;
                then
                    a=$a"echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/value"
                fi
                #If temperature is between 40 and 42.99, the fan will start with 1 second burst and 1 second sleep
                if [[ $(bc <<< "$temp >= 40 && $temp <= 44") == 1 ]] ;
                then
                    a=$a"echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/value; sleep 0.5; echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/value; sleep 0.1 "
                fi
                #If temperature is between 43 and 47.99, the fan will start with 1 second burst and 0.5 second sleep
                if [[ $(bc <<< "$temp >= 45 && $temp <= 47") == 1 ]] ;
                then
                    a=$a"echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/value; sleep 1; echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/value; sleep 0.5" 
                fi
                #If temperature is equal or higher than 48, the fan will start spinning constantly
                if [[ $(bc <<< "$temp >= 48") == 1 ]] ;
                then
                    a=$a"echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/value" 
                fi
                
                eval $a
                sleep 0.1
            done
       
        touch $FLAG
    fi
) &> /home/pi/rpipwm.txt
```

Comment: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/40493/5538

Comment: I not understand this.

Comment: It will be hard to debug your problem then.  My point is as with any kind of persistent process if you do not arrange some kind of logging then it is difficult to say what it was doing at point A, B, C, and so on.  Logging is not hard to arrange.  It is certainly much easier than not doing it if you need to hypothesize about a problem which occurred, e.g., at point C.

Comment: Yeah you are right. I will read again and made debug of script. Interesting things is that on mynual run all work perfect.

Comment: Yes, as that generic question says, "I know the event is occurring and the script is executing, but it does not do what I intend. Strangely, *it does when I run it manually,* so I am very confused."  This is not an uncommon problem.  Note that processes started by init should background themselves and your script does not appear to do that.

Comment: I just update my script to see what error will catch. I'm confused because script work perfect but on auto execute stop working in 20min

Comment: I think what's happening is that you didn't actually write an `init` script to control this, you just put the script in `init.d`.  The scripts in the `init.d` directory are used to start/stop/etc. some *other* daemon and then they exit.  If they do not finish soon enough (I'd guess the value of "soon" on you system is 20 minutes), then `init` decides they are malfunctioning and kills them.  I think you need to read up more on how init scripts are supposed to work.

Comment: Yes maby. I put @goldilocks's instructions and now my script working properly and clean. I don't have any issue for now.

Comment: Why did you decide to assign commands to `$a` and use `eval $a` rather than execute the commands directly? And why don't you compare with `-gt` and `-lt`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an answer to the original question (as I understand, the problem disappeared on its own anyway), but rather a recommendation on your scripting.

I believe the big part of your problem is the `eval` statement. I don't see why you need it, and it certainly makes your code harder to debug. Also comparison operations could be made simpler using `-gt` and `-lt` operators.

Something like

```
        if [ $temp -lt 39 ] # temperature below 39
        then
            echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/value
        elif [ $temp -lt 44 ] # temperature above 39 but below 44
        then
            echo 1 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/value
            sleep 0.5
            echo 0 > /sys/class/gpio/gpio20/value
            sleep 0.1
        elif ... # next interval
            ... etc ...
        fi
```

With this code, you know for sure that (1) only one alternative can be executed at a time, and (2) the exact commands for each case. With `eval $a`, you can't be sure of anything unless you analyse all possible combinations of commands which modify `$a`.

Answer (score 0):

Enable auto start at boot:

sudo cp rpipwm.sh /etc/init.d/rpipwm.sh
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/rpipwm.sh
sudo update-rc.d /etc/init.d/rpipwm.sh defaults   not work