# Cron job won't run bash script

Tags: raspbian, script, cron

I'm trying to create a cron job that will run at the beginning of every hour on raspbian

My script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
timeout 150s chromium-browser http://touchcast.com/tjin_daily/tjin_news_5_17_17 --start-fullscreen
```

My cron job under pi is:

```
0 * * * * /home/pi/scripts/openvideo.sh
```

I have tested a simple echo "Hello" >>/home/pi/Documents/hi with success but my script refuses to run.

openvideo.sh has full permissions as well.

Comment: See also https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/40493/5538 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/12771333/1151724