# Executing multiple scripts on startup in a particular order

Tags: python, boot, systemd

I am running Raspbian GNU Linux (9) Stretch, on my Raspberry Pi 3.

### Project Overview

1. Python script which makes use of 2 inputs to the Pi. Calculations are performed based on these inputs, and values are stored in a database.
2. A separate Django website which reads values from this database and updates the content of the web page.

**Django Server** run using: `/home/pi/mysite/manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000`

**Python Script** located at: `/home/pi/Desktop/myscript.py`

On startup I would like to first make sure that my Django server is up and running and then start my python script.

### What I have done so far

I came across the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48195340/systemd-with-multiple-execstart), but this is not what I am looking for. However most of the information is highly relevant.

> if Type=simple in your unit file, you can only specify one ExecStart, but you can add as many ExecStartPre,ExecStartPost`, but none of this is suited for long running commands, because they are executed serially and everything one start is killed before starting the next one.

If Type=oneshot you can specify multiple ExecStart, they run serially not in parallel.

Initially I started by trying to get the python script to run on startup. To do this I am using a simple `systemd` service as follows.

```
[Unit]
Description=My script

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/myscript.py

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This runs without error and initiates the python script on startup.

However, I cannot get my Django server up and running inside the same systemd service since only one `ExecStart` is allowed. I need both to be run in parallel.

Any suggestions on how this can be done?-

Comment: The same question you link to has an answer that mentions target dependencies. I have to say the example is not very good / clear, but I do think that is one way of solving your issue.

Comment: I have been trying to interpret the answer and implement something similar but I have to admit that I'm struggling to get something to work on my end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solved

The simplest solution I found was to create another `Unit`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Mysite

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/mysite/manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

We can enable it using:

`rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable mysite.service`

Next we need to edit the `myscript.service`, such that this runs before `mysite.service`.

```
[Unit]
Description=My script

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/myscript.py
Wants=mysite.service 

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The difference between `Wants` and `Requires` can be found [here](https://fedoramagazine.org/systemd-unit-dependencies-and-order/).

Comment: Hi @Rrz0, well done with making a second Unit. This is the solution. But there is a mistake in *myscript.service*. For section `[Service]` is no option `Wants=` defined. This is only available for section `[Unit]`. Look at `man systemd.unit` and at `man systemd.service`. Add this two options to section `[Unit]`: `After=mysite.service` and `Wants=mysite.service`. That would do the thing.