# Why does my Python scripts fail to run at boot?

Tags: python, pi-2

I have a number of sensors connected to my pi 3 and i put the python scripts (7 of them) that starts the sensors at boot in the /etc/profile/ folder.. Of the 7 scripts, i noticed that only the scripts that turns on a led and the 16x2 lcd runs at startup no matter where i put the scripts, (be it rc.local or chrontab) the other scripts that should startup my ldr, mq5, dht11, pir sensors do not run at startup.

I also should not fail to mention that the problem started after i used the "kill all python" command one day.
While i was trouble shooting this issue i backed up my sd card and re-flashed an earlier image of my sd card and all the scripts booted with the pi. But the thing is i do not want to have to start my project all over again. How can i force all scripts to startup with my pi?

- EDITED
  What i'm saying is that i put 7 python scripts in /etc/profiles/ to run at startup. only 3 of the 7 scripts initiate at startup. I want to know the reason why and how to fix this.
  I also tried 3 other ways of running a script at startup but only 3 scripts end up starting with the pi. 4 fail to launch.

Comment: Although there are substantive differences between this and the duplicate, what they have in common is confusion about what "at boot" is and what `/etc/profile` is actually for (hint: it is **not** for running arbitrary programs at boot).  You need to get this clear in your head and choose a more appropriate method; what you have here boils down to, "I am doing this the wrong way. Why doesn't it work the way I want?" -> Because you are wasting your time trying to make the wrong way right.

Comment: Like I stated in the question, it does not matter where I put the scripts whether crontab or /etc/rc.local, 4 of the scrips that have to do with playing audio never loads.

Comment: Great, so you are saying no matter what you do it does not work -- then there is no point in asking for yet another way to do it. There is not an infinity of means, and *there are means which should work for everything.*  If the latter does not work, it is because you are doing something wrong.  **There is no information here that would allow anyone else to tell you what that is.** You need to try and do some debugging, e.g, via logging, and possibly using [a shell wrapper](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/40493/5538) to check the exit status of the things which supposedly "never load".

Answer (score 1):

To make your python script run at startup, you should write something like this in your rc.local files.

open file editor with your inbuilt software like, `nano /etc/rc.local`

`sudo /root/abc.py` (Note: here abc.py file is in root directory).

Comment: I did that but 4 scripts out of 7 never launch at startup with the rest.

Comment: sudo in a script is a bad idea since it expects a user interaction, typing in the password!