# How can I automate a command at boot with a Kali Linux distribution?

Tags: bluetooth, kali

I am following [this guide](https://hobbylad.wordpress.com/2016/10/13/rpi-control-over-bt-android/) to connect to a Raspberry Pi with Bluetooth and I would like the Pi to execute the following command at boot.

```
screen sudo rfcomm watch /dev/rfcomm0 1 /sbin/agetty rfcomm0 linux 115200
```

I have tried multiples to achieve it with the 2019.4 Kali Linux release but none of them succeeded.

**1)** Edit the `/etc/rc.local` file with the desired commands
**2)** Add the desired commands to `cron`
**3)** Execute the command with the automated startup in the Settings menu

So here are my questions:

**a)** Is it a special command that can't be executed at boot or there is something that makes it nonexecutable?

**b)** What should I do to launch this command at boot?

Comment: If you are doing this via rc.local or some other global mechanism there's no point to `sudo`, it's being run with privileges.  You've said it doesn't happen -- first check that rc.local is running with something like `date > /tmp/rc-local-check` (will leave a timestamp at boot in that file).  If it is running, then you need to find out if `screen` or something puts out any error messages by redirecting them to a file: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/40494/5538

Comment: In this way, after system boot, start running all the commands of the `rc.local`. So, `cat /var/log/syslog` and add the error of the command you added to `rc.local`. It's exactly after `screen sudo rfcomm watch /dev/rfcomm0 1 /sbin/agetty rfcomm0 linux 115200`.