# Python script refuses to start automatically

Tags: python, boot, script, cron, reboot

I have a python script (taken from the forums here) that reboots my RPI when a button is pressed.

It works great, no issues, except that it refuses to start automatically (either on boot, login, anything). I have tried various options listed [here](https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/) (rc.local, .bashrc, idit.d tab, systems, crontab) and nothing seems to work.

Is it something as simple as my script actually not being very good, and something in there is stopping it from working?

```
 #!/usr/bin/python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import os

def button_callback(channel):
    print("Button was pushed!")

GPIO.setwarnings(False)
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(16, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

def Restart(channel):
   os.system("sudo shutdown -r now")

GPIO.add_event_detect(16,GPIO.RISING,callback = Restart, bouncetime = 2000)

message = input()

GPIO.cleanup()
```

Comment: May be useful: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/40493/5538

Comment: Thanks @goldilocks , I'll give it a thorough read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess the script is immediately terminated when run in the background because of the `message = input()` line.  The script's input and output will not be set to the devices you expect (screen and keyboard).

Replace that line with an eternal while loop.  Something like the following.

```
while True:
   time.sleep(60)
```