# Pi Zero W headless issue

Tags: ssh, pi-zero-w, headless, ping

I’ve got a pi0W running headless. I’ve always been able to ssh without issue.

I recently updated crontab to run a new script, but it appears the script failed to run (because it is supposed to transfer some files to a network drive), or the script is hung up or something. I can see it’s still connected to my network and I am able to ping it from a windows 10 machine, but when I try to ssh it will let me enter the user, but it never prompts me for a password. It will never fully connect.

How do I resolve this? Short of just powering it off. It’s located in a place and in an enclosure where I am unable to hook a display to it (without powering it off).

What are my options?

Comment: your options are to power it off

Comment: You can try `ssh -v` (or `-vv`) to get more debugging info but as per last comment sometimes there's no other option but to cycle the power.   You might want to add a watchdog and/or reset button.

Comment: @goldilocks I’ll look into using a watchdog timer, but any suggestions on what to check after power cycling the pi to try to determine the cause?

Comment: You could check the system logs, but there may not be much of a clue.  You need to implement some logging to determine what happens with the script. https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/40493/5538 <-  It's presented in relation to a bash script, but you can wrap the execution of anything that way.  There are other better ways, of course, but that one is simple and easy.