# rc.local server boot using screen not working

Tags: pi-4, screen, server

I have a Nukkit (not Bukkit) Minecraft server, and I want it to start on boot. The command to run the server is `java -jar nukkit/nukkit.jar`. I want to run it in a detached screen command with the name Minecraft, so this is what I put in rc.local (right before `exit 0`): `screen -d -m -S Minecraft java -jar nukkit/nukkit.jar`. Then it just doesn't run. Whenever I type `screen -r Minecraft` it tells me that there's no screen session named that, and the server isn't being hosted at all. Anybody know what's wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`screen` sessions are I would presume (I'm a tmux user) *per user*.  When you log in, whoever you logged in as doesn't own that session.

You could check this by using `sudo screen -r ...`.

Try replace `rc.local` with:

```
#!/bin/bash

(
    su pi - c "screen -d -m -S Minecraft java -jar /absolute/path/nukkit/nukkit.jar"
) &> /var/log/init_nukkit.log
```

You might want to check the path of the `su`, `screen`, and `java` commands and use try adding those in if this doesn't work.

If `pi` is not the user you want, use that as the 1st arg to `su` instead. Also note the `#!/bin/bash`, not `/bin/sh`, so that `&>` works; see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/40494/5538